# Running a shell script through Ruby which brings back the first echo statement instead of the full output

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and to net:ssh.

I am trying to execute a shell script via net::ssh and my problem is the shell script takes a bit longer to return the output and by the time it comes back the script returns the first echo statement displayed and closes the connection.

Below is the part of the script:

```
ssh = Net::SSH.start(hostname, username, :password => password)
test = ssh.exec!("~/usr/bin/dbversion")
ssh.close
return test
```

dbversion script has a sql statement to execute and has an echo statement before saying 'please wait...'

My output currently just brings back 'please wait..' echo statement and doesn't wait for the script to fully execute and bring back the results.

Is there a way I can make it wait while its executing the query rather than just printing the first echo statement ?

Hope I was clear in explaining the issue.

Thanks

Below is the dbversion Script:

```
outputFile=~/ers/log/dbversion.log
echo -e "\nPlease wait - gathering information"
myDBInfo=`runselect "
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'ih 08' AS LN, 'Last_DB_Transaction_Date' AS parameter, TO_CHAR (greatest(
        (SELECT     MAX (update_datetime)  AS VALUE FROM case.case_transaction),
        (SELECT     MAX (update_datetime) AS VALUE FROM case.completed_case_transaction)),
                   'DD MON YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                    AS VALUE
            FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'ih 01' as LN, 'DB_Service_Name'  AS parameter, SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','service_name')  AS value FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'ih 02' as LN, 'DB_Database_Name' AS parameter, SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','db_name')       AS value FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'ih 03' as LN, 'DB_Instance_Name' AS parameter, SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','instance_name') AS value FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'ih 04' as LN, 'DB_ERS_Release'   AS parameter, release_number || '.' || release_increment AS value FROM user.application_version UNION
  SELECT 'ih 05' as LN, 'DB_ERS_Build'     AS parameter, build_number  AS value FROM user.application_version UNION
  SELECT 'ih 06' as LN, 'DTC_Version'      AS parameter, TO_CHAR(MAX(versionno)) AS value FROM dtc.versionhistory UNION
  SELECT 'ih 07' as LN, 'MDD_Version'      AS parameter, TO_CHAR(MAX(mdd_version_number)) AS value FROM edmdd.mdd_version_number UNION
  SELECT 'ih 09' as LN, 'Oracle_Version'   AS parameter, regexp_substr(banner, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, 5 ) AS value from v\\$version where banner like 'Oracle%'
  ) order by 1
  " fatal.lcf 2>/dev/null | grep -e "^ih" | awk -F, '{ printf ("%24s : %s\n", $2, $3); }' | sed -e 's/_/ /g;s/\(.*DB ERS Release.*\)\.\.\(.*\)/\1\.0\.\2/g'`
myEnv=`basename ~ | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`
myDBInfo=`echo "${myDBInfo}" | sed -e "s/ #//g;/EPOS/{/${myEnv}/!s/\( *\)\( EPOS.*\)/\1\x1B[41;1m\2 \x1B[0;0m/g;};s/ ${myEnv}/\x1B[42;30m ${myEnv} \x1B[0;0m/g;"`
echo -e "${myDBInfo}\n" > ${outputFile}
cat ${outputFile}
```

Comment: Can you include the dbversion script? Or at least a similar script that causes a similar problem? I see no reason why this wouldn't work as-is.

Comment: @Max, Thanks. Please find below the Shell script (dbversion.sh). Too big to add it as a comment.

Comment: I have edited the Original Post to include the script. Thanks

Comment: Alas, I still cannot reproduce the problem. Have you run the script directly to ensure that it outputs the correct result? Have you tried running a simpler script to see if you still get the same problem? Is the correct output of the script extremely large? If so, Ruby might simply be blocking on I/O. You can try using `Net::SSH#open_channel` to handle the output in smaller chunks.

Comment: @Max, I have run simpler commands to get the date and it returns the output without issues. its not too big output and my guess is its taking time to run the sql and net::ssh returns the output before the shell script completes. Its working perfectly in a linux environment when executed directly. Thanks for looking into this.